# Kommas in Fragen

Tags: comma

Wie sieht's bezüglich der Kommasetzung bei folgenden Sätzen aus:

> 1. Ist deine Aussage nun wahr(,) oder ist sie falsch?
> 2. Wie alt bist du(,) und wo kommst du her?

Comment: Es sieht gut aus.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn *und* oder *oder* gleichrangige Hauptsätze verbindet, steht im Allgemeinen kein Komma. Hierzu heißt es in § 72 des amtlichen Regelwerks:

> Sind die gleichrangigen Teilsätze, Wortgruppen oder Wörter durch *und, oder, beziehungsweise/bzw., sowie (= und), wie (= und), entweder … oder, nicht … noch, sowohl … als (auch), sowohl … wie (auch)* oder durch *weder … noch* verbunden, so setzt man kein Komma.

Das Komma ist aber nicht falsch. Um die Gliederung der Satzverbindung deutlich zu machen, kann man gemäß § 73 ein Komma setzen:

> Bei der Reihung von selbständigen Sätzen, die durch *und, oder, beziehungsweise/
>   bzw., entweder – oder, nicht – noch* oder durch *weder – noch* verbunden sind, kann man ein Komma setzen, um die Gliederung des Ganzsatzes deutlich zu machen.

Die entsprechenden Rechtschreibregel im aktuellen Duden ist [Regel 119](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K119).

Ein Komma vor *und* oder *oder* zwischen gleichrangigen Hauptsätzen kann außerdem durch eine andere Regel begründet sein (z. B. bei einem eingeschobenen Nebensatz). Das ist allerdings in diesem Fall nicht gegeben.

Answer (score 0):

Nach der neuen Deutschen Rechtschreibung ist das Setzen des Kommas vor Konjunktionen erlaubt.